# apt-get update size mismatch error

Tags: apt, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 vivid. When I try to update I get a `Size mismatch` error like the one below:

```
$apt-get update
...                           
Get:92 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/main rename all 0.20-3 [11.9 kB]
Get:93 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid/main libcgi-fast-perl all 1:2.04-1 [9984 B]
Fetched 17.5 MB in 38s (458 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/i/isc-dhcp/isc-dhcp-common_4.3.1-5ubuntu2.2_ppc64el.deb  Size mismatch
```

and the corresponding line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` is the following:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid universe
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Why you use `deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid universe`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a temporary error. Try it again later and have patience. **;)**

And there is no reason to use

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid universe
```

in a Vivid installation.

Therefore remove the line in your `sources.list`

```
sudo sed -i '/ports\.ubuntu\.com/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: i am trying from last 2 days having same issue

Comment: @Ravi_SS Then go to "System Settings", "Software&Updates", in the first tab ("Ubuntu Software") change the "Download from:" option to "Main Server" or try any other mirror in your region. Some servers like maybe the one you are currently using are sometimes up to a few days behind...

Comment: i am having a new system from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/15.04/release/ubuntu-core-15.04-core-ppc64el.tar.gz